# Setting all images to ImageSize->Small

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

Is there a way that I can set the image size of all images in a notebook to ImageSize->Small in some sort of initialization cell?

**Update:** Following Szabolcs's helpful advice, here is what happened to the Manipulate.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{t + 2 Sin[2 t], t + 2 Cos[5 t]}, {t, -2 Pi, tau}, 
  PlotRange -> 9],
 {tau, -2 Pi + 0.1, 2 Pi}]
```

The axes are somewhat shifted to the left. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Alignment->Center?

Comment: I guess, you need just kill the dynamic object of Manipulate and restart it again or may be play with `ImageMargins` or `ImagePadding` for the graphics inside the `Manipulate`

Answer (score 6):

Set `ImageSize` in `GraphicsBoxOptions` for the current notebook within the Option Inspector.

[image]

This will affect existing and future graphics in the notebook that have `ImageSize -> Automatic`.

To do this programmatically, evaluate

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {GraphicsBoxOptions, ImageSize}] = Small
```

in the notebook you wish to change.

Comment: The program code worked, but it also performed a weird affect on my Manipulate examples in my notebook. Any suggestions?